# Execute sub query dependant on parameter/variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

### My Question

I am trying to execute a query within a `MERGE` query in order to pull results from one table into another. This all works fine apart from one little hickup...

The query that is executed to get the data from the table is dependant on a variable called `@User_ID`.

If `@User_ID` is `NULL` then execute subquery A, else execute subquery B.

The issue that I have is that I do not know how to place an `IF` within a subquery... How can I do this?

### What I have tried...

This is what I have so far:

***Please note, this may work but as I am running SQL Server 2008 not 2012 (I think), the `IIF` function is not available I think, so I need another method of achieving this.***

```
-- Get the relevant logins for the past 12 weeks and insert
-- them into the temporary table where the week number is the same
MERGE INTO #Number_Of_Logins AS NOL
USING (
    SELECT IIF (ISNULL(@User_ID,0), (
            SELECT 
                Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num,
                DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number,
                Count(*) AS Num_Logins
            FROM User_Auditing UA
            WHERE Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
                AND User_ID = @User_ID
                AND DATEDIFF(wk, Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
            GROUP BY Year(Audit_When), DatePart(wk, Audit_When)
        ),
        (
            SELECT 
                Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num,
                DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number,
                Count(*) AS Num_Logins
            FROM User_Auditing UA
                JOIN User_Profiles UP ON UA.User_ID = UP.User_ID
            WHERE UA.Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
                AND UP.Company_ID = @Company_ID
                AND DATEDIFF(wk, UA.Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
            GROUP BY Year(Audit_When), DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When)
        )
    )
) AS TEST
ON NOL.Week_Number = TEST.Week_Number
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
    SET Number_Of_Logins = Num_Logins;
```

### Update

I have also tried using `CASE`, and I get the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: It might just be my terrible eyesight but those two queries look identical

Comment: @RichardNewman Well spotted, in this example they are but they are not meant to be. Will update. Thank you for pointing it out! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution, no need to control flow at such a high level.

```
MERGE INTO #Number_Of_Logins AS NOL
USING (
    SELECT 
                Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num,
                DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number,
                Count(*) AS Num_Logins
            FROM User_Auditing UA
                LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Profiles UP ON UA.User_ID = UP.User_ID
            WHERE Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
                AND ( User_ID = @User_ID
                    OR ( @User_ID IS NULL
                       AND UP.Company_ID = @Company_ID 
                    )
                )
                AND DATEDIFF(wk, Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
            GROUP BY Year(Audit_When), DatePart(wk, Audit_When)
) AS TEST
ON NOL.Week_Number = TEST.Week_Number
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
    SET Number_Of_Logins = Num_Logins;
```

In this example the second condition of the where clause says:
either the @User_ID is provided
OR the user ID is null and the company ID's match.

If either of those conditions are met along with your other conditions then include this record. That should encapsulate all the information you require with no complicated nested selects.

Comment: Looks great, but what about the `JOIN`?

Comment: Good spot, there was me assuming the queries were the same apart from that bit. A left outer join should take care of that.
See my updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Without testing your query, there is an obvious problem, and I can quickly propose one kind of solution.

**The problem:** `CASE` expressions and `IIF` function calls work with values, not resultsets. Your proposed approach above would not work in SQL Server 2012 either, for that reason.

**One possible solution:** use a `UNION ALL` to combine your two possible queries, with different WHERE clauses to do the filtering of one or the other resultset:

```
-- Get the relevant logins for the past 12 weeks and insert
-- them into the temporary table where the week number is the same
MERGE INTO #Number_Of_Logins AS NOL
USING (
        SELECT 
            Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num,
            DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number,
            Count(*) AS Num_Logins
        FROM User_Auditing UA
        WHERE Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
            AND User_ID = @User_ID
            AND DATEDIFF(wk, Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
            AND @User_ID Is Not Null
        GROUP BY Year(Audit_When), DatePart(wk, Audit_When)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num,
            DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number,
            Count(*) AS Num_Logins
        FROM User_Auditing UA
            JOIN User_Profiles UP ON UA.User_ID = UP.User_ID
        WHERE UA.Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
            AND UP.Company_ID = @Company_ID
            AND DATEDIFF(wk, UA.Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
            AND @User_ID Is Null
        GROUP BY Year(Audit_When), DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When)
    )
) AS TEST
ON NOL.Week_Number = TEST.Week_Number
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
    SET Number_Of_Logins = Num_Logins;
```

**Another option:** have two entirely separate MERGE statements, with an IF statement choosing which one to execute (more duplicated code, but could have query caching / performance benefits):

```
-- Get the relevant logins for the past 12 weeks and insert
-- them into the temporary table where the week number is the same
IF @User_ID IS NOT NULL
    MERGE INTO #Number_Of_Logins AS NOL
    USING (
        SELECT Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num
            ,DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number
            ,Count(*) AS Num_Logins
        FROM User_Auditing UA
        WHERE Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
            AND User_ID = @User_ID
            AND DATEDIFF(wk, Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
        GROUP BY Year(Audit_When)
            ,DatePart(wk, Audit_When)
        ) AS TEST
        ON NOL.Week_Number = TEST.Week_Number
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET Number_Of_Logins = Num_Logins;
ELSE
    MERGE INTO #Number_Of_Logins AS NOL
    USING (
        SELECT Year(UA.Audit_When) AS Year_Num
            ,DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When) AS Week_Number
            ,Count(*) AS Num_Logins
        FROM User_Auditing UA
        INNER JOIN User_Profiles UP ON UA.User_ID = UP.User_ID
        WHERE UA.Audit_Type = 'SYSLI'
            AND UP.Company_ID = @Company_ID
            AND DATEDIFF(wk, UA.Audit_When, GETDATE()) <= 11
        GROUP BY Year(Audit_When)
            ,DatePart(wk, UA.Audit_When)
        ) AS TEST
        ON NOL.Week_Number = TEST.Week_Number
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET Number_Of_Logins = Num_Logins;
```

I would likely go with the second option, for the (potential) performance benefits.

Comment: Will the above not have query caching? What method would you choose? Duplicate code and an `IF` statement, or as you have done above? Where would I put the `WHERE` clause? What results are returned with this? The companies or the users? Really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: `UNION` queries prevent auto-parameterisation, so prevent caching for ad-hoc queries; that said, no difference in a proc. I would choose the second option, for that reason if nothing else (also, having separate statements allows each to be cached with a more-likely-to-be-optimal plan, individually). As to what results are returned, I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: No probs, have worked it all out now. Thank you so much! :-). For the purposes of accepting the best answer, what are your views on the other answer that has been posted? Is it a better solution?

Comment: Hah, that very subjective, and definitely depends on your database structure :) - the other solution is certainly much simpler / more maintainable code, and will likely perform no worse in most situations, but I would argue that it doesn't answer your question regarding "If @User_ID is NULL then execute subquery A, else execute subquery B". I believe the other answer is probably better code for your case, anyway!